# Angular observable subscribe JSON parsing issue

Tags: json, api, observable, angular8

I have a service performing `http.get` on a Drupal API and retrieving JSON data.

The component utilising that JSON data keeps generating the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/form-test/form-test.component.ts(18,28): error TS2551: Property 'included' does not exist on type 'Question[]'. Did you mean 'includes'?
```

From the following code:

```
constructor(private dataService: QuizService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetch().subscribe(data => {
        this.jsondata = data.included[0].attributes.field_json;
        console.log(data, ': DATA');
    });
}
```

I don't understand why there is a problem with the JSON and why it's trying to find includes instead of included in the JSON structure. Below is a screenshot of a sample of the JSON:

[image]

I have confirmed the structure of the JSON data (as confirmed from the image above), also from console logging the JSON data and that the API URL is live at the time Ay angular app is attempting to call it.

Can anyone advice what is the cause of this error and how can I resolve it?

**UPDATE:**

*quiz.service.ts*:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Question {
  // title: string;
  question: string;
  included: any[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class QuizService {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  private quizURL: string = 'http://drupal-8-composer-drupal-test.com/jsonapi/node/quiz/31f020f7-34d9-4b9a-bd2b-0d567eb285dc/?include=field_questions&fields%5Bnode--quiz%5D=title,drupal_internal__nid,body&fields%5Bnode--question%5D=title,field_processed,body,field_options,field_json';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    fetch(): Observable<Question[]> {
      return this.httpClient.get<Question[]>( this.quizURL );
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please include QuizService code or at least the fetch method?

Comment: @AntonRusak: Apologies for the delay. I updated the question with the quiz.service.ts code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `data` has type Question[]. It is an array, not an object. Typescript compiler tries to find an `included` variable in array and there's none. So it gives you an error.

Your JSON structure contains an array of questions in the `included` field. So the type which the `fetch` returns should be like `{ included: Question[] }`:

```
    fetch(): Observable<{ included: Question[] }> {
      return this.httpClient.get<{ included: Question[] }>( this.quizURL );
    }
```

Or you can process the response in service and return questions only:

```
fetch(): Observable<Question[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.quizURL)
      .pipe(map((data: { included: Question[] }) => data.included));
}
```

`.map` operator gets the whole response object, extracts only questions and returns them as array.